# GORM and Composite Keys in associations

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have legacy database and some tables have composite ids

```
class Client {
   String id

   static hasMany = [
      settings: Setting
   ]

   static mapping = {
      id column: 'client_id', generator: 'assigned'
   }
}

class Setting {
   Client client
   String nodeId
   String ccyPairPattern
   Character qualifier

   static mapping = {
      id composite: ['client', 'nodeId', 'pattern', 'qualifier']
   }
}
```

I want to delete entry from GORM association:

```
client.get('1').removeFromSettings(settingToRemove)
// settingToRemove.delete(flush: true) 
// delete-orphans does not help
```

This always raises  exception after flush

```
 org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by      another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) :
```

This happens because method removeFrom* sets client property to null and generates query to delete with clientId = null as client is part of composite key

What is the best solution in this case. Looks like GORM has poor support for composite keys or my mapping is incorrect.

Comment: Also GORM unit tests shows odd behavior on the setup above. If add equals/hashcode to Settings class it will have duplicate rows once the rows are saved

Answer (score 0):

When you use *hasMany* without a *belongsTo* on the many side, in other words a unidirectional association, you get a join table. For example...

```
class PurchaseOrder {
    static hasMany = [items: Item]
}

class Item { }
```

Would yield three database tables: *purchase_order*, *item*, and *purchase_order_items*. The *purchase_order_items* table would contain two columns: *purchase_order_id* and *item_id*. You can read more about join tables [here](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html).

Since you're dealing with a legacy database, I think the best solution is not to use `addTo*()` and `removeFrom*()`.

1. Ensure you don't have a join table. If you have a join table, remove the *hasMany* association.
2. You'll need to add/remove `Setting` instances manually.

**Example:**

```
def client = Client.get(1)

// Adding a setting
def setting = new Setting(client: client, nodeId: blah...)
setting.save()

// Removing a setting

/*
 The prototype is used to search for a domain instance with a composite primary key.
 So simply set the composite key properties accordingly.
*/
def prototype = new Setting(client: client, nodeId: blah...)
def setting = Setting.get(prototype)
setting.delete()
```

Lacking a *hasMany* association, you won't be able to access a client's settings via the `client.settings` property. Instead you'd have to query for them like this:

```
def settings = Setting.findByClient(client)
```

A consequence of using a legacy database is that if the database doesn't align with that GORM/Hibernate expects it will be limited in what it can do for you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I am using something similar as workaround and keep hasMany association. But this looks odd. I wondering if a proper solution exists. Does hibernate has the same issue or it's one of gorm - hibernate missing features.

Comment: In addition, according to hibernate logs my mapping does not use join table at all